# Django ORM Get users not assigned to the Team

Tags: python, django, django-orm

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class UserGroup(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members', through='UserGroupMember')


class UserGroupMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    usergroup = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup)


class Cohort(models.Model):
    user_groups = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup)


class Team(models.Model):
    cohort = models.ForeignKey(Cohort)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='team_members', through='TeamMembers', blank=True)


class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Single user can be part of only one team within a cohort.

**Query #1**

I need to write the query to get the users for a given cohort that are not assigned to any team.

I tried this:

```
User.objects.filter(
    members__cohort=cohort
).filter(
    team_members__isnull=True
)
```

but that does not give me the user if he is part of the team in another cohort.

**Query #2**

I want to annotate the new field (boolean) which tells you is the user assigned to some team in the cohort, something like:

```
User.objects.filter(
    members__cohort=cohort
).annotate(
    is_team_member=...
)
```

---

I am using Python 2.7.13 and Django 1.9.8. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing the queryset by excluding all the members that *are* assigned to a team in the cohort:

```
User.objects.filter(
    members_cohort=cohort,
).exclude(
    team_members__cohort=cohort,
)
```

Comment: Perfect! It works, thanks. Can you please check the edited version (Query #2)?

Comment: People won't see your follow up question now that you've accepted my answer. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663027/django-orm-annotate-boolean-field-that-defines-is-user-member-of-a-team

Comment: Btw, we need double underscore like `team_members__cohort`.